# No libgobject-2.0.so.0 when run GUI aplication

Tags: linux, centos, qt

I have compiled qt widget GUI application on Centos 6.9 32 bit and trying to run on Centos 7 64 bit machine. I have copied required QT libraries, but when I try to run application I have error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: 
libgobject-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You don't have `libgobject-2.0` library on Centos 7. Try to install [`glib2` library](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libgobject-2.0.so.0%28%29%2864bit%29&submit=Search+...&system=Centos&arch=).

Answer (score 1):

Copying random libraries around is probably not a good idea. Instead, inspect the package system to see if a 32-bit version of the library is provided. RedHat calls 32-bit "i686":

```
# yum whatprovides '*/libgobject-2.0.so.0' | grep i686
glib2-2.54.2-2.el7.i686 : A library of handy utility functions
# yum install glib2.i686
...
```

It may be a better idea to avoid if possible running a multilib system soas to reduce complexity and lower the odds of yum wedging on a multilib package problem. This would require recompiling all software as 64-bit.